# Do the Steam versions of the X-Com games have the original bugs fixed?

Tags: steam, xcom-ufo-defense

Has anyone played these on Steam? Are the bugs fixed?

Bugs I remember:

- All difficulties are the same.
- Infinite Fuel Glitch
- Shooting (and seeing) through some walls.
- Item spawn limits when aliens attack a base.

This would be the original game. UFO Defense a.k.a. Enemy Unknown

Comment: Which in the series are you referring to?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, the game is exactly the same as the original, run through DosBox.

Still a great game to play though :)

Answer (score 12):

There is a software tool called Xcom Util (http://www.bladefirelight.com/) ( referenced on the Steam forums here along with Steam install instructions :- http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1113400) that fixes some of the bugs and adds a number of helpful features and tweaks to improve the game. It's certainly worth examining.

Comment: This breathes new life into the game, and new conveniences. It can rename your soldiers for you according to their stats. It will remember what equipment each soldier had at the end of the last mission and auto equip them for you saving tremendous amounts of time. Making research dependent on capturing aliens makes the game tremendously more difficult and fights more interesting.

Answer (score 11):

The Steam version still uses the original game.  None of the bugs are game-breaking, but they are worth knowing about.

Check them out [Here](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Known_Bugs).

My favorite?  The [Paying for Dirt](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Known_Bugs#Paying_For_Dirt) bug.  Be mindful or you will wonder where all your money went. :)

Comment: But it's *nice* dirt.

Comment: Whoa. I've played through that game many times and yet never noticed most of those bugs. Now I want to play it again just to (re)discover them all.

Answer (score 2):

Some fans have made a Windows clone. It requires that you own the original DOS version (easily acquired from steam).

http://openxcom.org/

The feature I'm most interested in is

> Fixability: Play the game natively without any need for emulators or
>   fancy hacks, ***with none of the limitations and bugs that plagued the
>   original***. No more 80-item-limit, personnel limits, funding overflows,
>   disconnected facilities, broken proximity grenades, floating soldiers,
>   etc.

Emphasis mine.